# Power BI embedded, Issue with using Certificate for getting authentication token - Getting error 'invalid provider type'

Tags: .net, powerbi, x509certificate, powerbi-embedded, cryptographicexception

I am using power BI embedded on the on premises intranet app and to get the authentication token, I am using Certificate. 
The issue i am facing is, when doing locally it works fine. But when posting to our Dev server, it is working on one instance but not on others like QA or UAT environment on premises.

what could be the reason for this? is it because we are not using the certificate properly? 
wierd thing is if it is failing, why is it working fine for just one instance of webserver and not other webservers?

****Here is the code snippet we are using for getting the authentication token:****

```
            var tenantSpecificURL = AuthorityUrl.Replace("common", Tenant);
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(tenantSpecificURL);
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var certificatepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"App_Data\SFA.pfx";
            var xCert = new X509Certificate2(certificatepath, "XXXXXXX", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            var credential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(ApplicationId, xCert);

            //this is where i believe it is failing
            authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, credential).Result;

            //End of Authentication
            string AccessToken = null; //
            var m_tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
            string Token = "";
```

This is the error I am getting.

**ExceptionMessage":"Invalid provider type 
specified.\r\n","ExceptionType":"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException","StackTrace":"   at** System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetAsymmetricAlgorithm(String algorithm, Boolean privateKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Platform.SigningHelper.SignWithCertificate(String message, X509Certificate2 certificate)\r\n   at

**Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__59.MoveNext()"}**

Comment: How you generated key pair for your certificate? What process did you use?

Comment: We used open SSL to generate private key.  As I mentioned, it is working fine locally and also on one instance of Dev server. what i want to undertand is...when we use PFX file for authentication from webserver(to call microsoft power bi rest api) does it leave any print in the webserver certificate folder that i first use..that now if i deploy in another server.it will not work in another webserver? i thought when we use pfx file.it can be deployed across multiple werbserver with the same pfx file.Still a rookie in certificate world so appreicate your help.Willing to put a bounty for solution